# Completeness of moves for polygonal knots

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, polygons

I am going through the paper, [MINIMAL KNOTTING NUMBERS](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218216509007373?journalCode=jktr), by MANN et. al. On page six of the paper, they defined following moves for polygonal knots.

1. Parallel moves
2. Triangular moves

I understand that this set of moves is complete for any polygonal knots. Is there a theorem on this? Any reference please?

Comment: Lickorish's book on knot theory has a sketch.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [Reidemeister moves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reidemeister_move) has citations.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip , after a quick scan through the whole book I understand that only chapter 1 discusses the triangle moves from page 11 onwards. I was not able to find any explicit theorem or formal mention about any sketch of proof. Nevertheless I found the following statement in page 12 - "If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are equivalent, they are related by a sequence of triangle moves as described above". Is this what you are talking about?